# Touchpad on mac not working when ubuntu 12.04 is on .. how to fix touchpad in ubuntu on macbook pro?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, touchpad, configuration-files

So this is my problem :

I have a macbook pro. I have installed linux on a separate partition (Ubuntu 12.04) and everything was working fine (touchpad, keyboard, etc) and it was perfect. One day, I decided to download a program called wine for gaming purposes. After I did that and rebooted, the mouse (or touchpad) wouldn't work anymore (NOTE: The touchpad is working fine when I boot into mac osx but it does not work when I boot into ubuntu). Now I don't know if the direct cause for it not to work is me downloading wine or if its for any other reason, my question is:

How can I solve this problem?

How do I completely remove wine from my system with all of the files that come with it ? (If that even is the problem)

Is there some kind of configuration file for the touchpad found in the ubuntu system ? If so how do i access it and check it and alter it to work again or something. I just need any solution to this problem I really need the touchpad to work again. NOTE: Connecting an external mouse while booted in ubuntu MAKES THE MOUSE WORK but I don't want that I want the touchpad of the macbook pro to work.

Another side note : the program i use to dual boot is rEEfit.(I can access EFI shell from there .. Is that useful at all ?)

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

Wine is a software which helps to run windows applications under linux OS. It has nothing to do with your macbook touchpad drivers. Did you install any drivers or enable any PPAs? did you do a system upgrade just before it worked?

The touchpad on Macbook has always been less than perfect under Ubuntu but have a look at this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126526/how-can-i-personalize-my-macbook-pro-touchpad) and the guides [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro). If you still cannot get it working it might be better if you post the question on [Ask Ubuntu](http://AskUbuntu.com).